# How to avoid extra nesting in json string

Tags: json, extjs

I tried to create json string according to syntax from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). I created json string with the following code:

```
        var data = [];
        
        data.push(
            {
                "firstName": "John",
                "lastName": "Smith",
                "isAlive": true,
                "age": 27,      
            });
            
        var addressdata = [];   

        addressdata.push(
                    {
                        "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
                        "city": "New York",
                        "state": "NY",
                        "postalCode": "10021-3100"
                    });
        
        data.push(
            {
                "address" : addressdata
            }
        );
```

The string is correct json string. However, the json structure contains some unnecessary nesting, as shown in the Figures 1 and 2 below. More precisely, there are surplus braces for address block, and the string is also enclosured with brackets instead of braces. So, what am I doing wrong? How can I avoid this unnecessary nesting and get structure as shown in Fig. 3?

[image]
Fig. 1

[image]
Fig. 2

[image]
Fig. 3

The string is generated with `jsonData : data,` in Ajax request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a list for the `data` variable. That's why you get brackets in the beginning and end of the JSON body. To overcome this problem you can declare the whole JSON body in the `data` variable like:

```
data = {
  "firstname": "test",
  (...)
  "address": [{
    "streetAddress": "test"
    (...)
  }]
}
```